# php include as rvalue?

Tags: php, caching, include, require, rvalue

I wonder if it is possible to use php `include` as a Rvalue, like this example:

```
$foo = include('bar.php);
```

I did a few experiments but it seems to not be possible.

The php files that I would like to load in this way are cached dumps of objects and arrays, saved with the `var_export()` function.

It is quite important to me to load those file with `import` (or `require`) and not with the normal file operations in order to get the full advantage of PHP's internal code caching system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either use [serialize](http://php.net.serialize) instead of var_export (and then use *normal* file operations) or make your dumper a bit more intelligent, adding variable itself to the dump (making it `$var=dump;`, not just `dump`)

Comment: serialize is a nice function, but I need to use `import` or `require` in order to use the PHP internal caching system for the sources. I cannot do a file read operation every time the page is loaded.